# Linux command to return the server logged into

Tags: linux, terminal

I keep finding the wrong answer. I have numerous Terminal windows opened at a time and ...if I get distracted to another job and come back, I'd like a fast way to see where I'm currently logged into as to the server.

Because I'm working on a Drupal site, there are two separate servers that are identical in structure so I'm trying to avoid scrolling back up or using history and looking. My prompts are identical on two different servers so there's no quick reference by that.

`Netstat` isn't really doing it because the IP's are different and not recognizable immediately and `arp` was close but shows the firewalls IP instead of the specific server.

I set aliases for say, www.server1.com and www.server2.com so I can log in fast...and as I mentioned, the day gets busy so I want to pick a terminal window, type a command and boom see, "Ahh this is server1.com"

Is there a command that in effect says "You're currently logged into...and the IP# or human-readable url, either is fine.

I've color-coded other server Terminal windows which is kinda cool but I'm sure there is some command I just have found yet?

Comment: you can set the `PS1` environment variable to show the hostname by including `\H` in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hostname** prints the currently logged in host's name.

**ifconfig** should show the IP address.

Setting bash environmnet variables such as PS1 can get you a prompt. For example:

```
export PS1="\u@\h:\w\n\$ "
```

This would display the logged in user, hostname and the current working directory in the prompt.

Adding the export to your $HOME/.bashrc should keep it persistent.

UPDATE:
Since you say the IP address is different between both the systems, you could add this to your bashrc (change eth0 to whatever interface it is known by on your system)

```
HOST_IPADDR=$(ifconfig eth0 | sed -n '/inet /{s/.*addr://;s/ .*//;p}')
if [ "$HOST_IPADDR" == "a.b.c.d" ]; then
    export PS1="\u@\h-DEV:\w\n\$ "
elif [ "$HOST_IPADDR" == "e.f.g.h" ]; then
    export PS1="\u@\h-PROD:\w\n\$ "
fi
```

Comment: thanks all, but `hostname` returns the same thing on both windows..in other words, my prompt already reads "admin@drupal6;~$" in both windows since all in the dev environment is the same as the live. And `ifconfig`shows IP's before the firewall, which yes I could memorize but I'd rather see the actual ip

Comment: Is the ssh command to login to both the systems the same ?

Comment: Except for the server address

Comment: Updated the answer, to set PS1 based on IP address.

Answer (score 1):

```
hostname
```

prints the name of your current host. You might also want to put the hostname in your prompt by modifying the `PS1` variable (in Bash), e.g.

```
PS1='\u@\h \w'
```

to get prompts like

```
username@someserver /tmp$
```

(put that in your `.bashrc` to make it persist beyond login sessions).